# Can't open a .jar file on my mac

Tags: java, macos, jar, jsoup

I'm trying to download jsoup on my mac (Mountain Lion). I've downloaded the `jsoup.jar` file and installed the last java 7 from the site. But here is the problem, when I double click the `.jar` file it tells to me:

> The Java JAR file “jsoup-1.7.2.jar” could not be launched. Check the
>   console.

I can't find even the console! Someone can help me? I read a lot of answers about this topic, but they all talk about Java 6 and it has different settings that can't find.

EDIT

i also tried from the terminal with this command:

> java -jar /Users/Ben/Downloads/jsoup-1.7.2.jar

but it tells me:

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
>   /Users/Ben/Downloads/jsoup-1.7.2.jar

Comment: show the command you are using to run the jar file

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Did you check the concerned documentation regarding its usage ?

Comment: it seems that jsoup is not an executable jar file and instead it means that is a library. By the way what you mean by "open" the jar? if you want to explore it, it's compatible with zip, so using a zip tool you can open it and explore it

Comment: @Santosh i've simply to start it. From the jsoup site (http://jsoup.org/download) they say to download this file

Comment: @fGo i think you're right, this mean that i 've to write a code myself to use its function?

Comment: @ciaomare, thats fine. You download the file and use that as a java library. I have posted link for examples of using jsoup as java library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to run the jsoup library as a standalone application assuming it to be an [executable jar](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/). All indicates that the jar file you are using is NOT an [executable jar](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/) hence it wont work.

jsoup.jar is supposed to be used as a java library and you will need to [write java code](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/) to be able to use the HTML parsing capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

The JSoup JAR is not executable, so you are not going to be able to 'run' it in any of the ways you described. You are supposed to include it in your project classpath and use classes from it to do your parsing (after importing them of course).

You might want to refer to the [JSoup Guide](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) for examples on using the library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like IntelliJ, you can open the **module settings** for a particular project and select **Libraries**. There'll be an option to add a particular external library from the Maven repository after which you can download the JAR and include it in your project's dependencies.